# Simple 301 .htaccess redirect creates infinite redirect on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've got a simple 301 redirect to send to get around having blank top level pages on my WP site:

```
Redirect 301 /page/ https://www.example.com/page/sub-page/
```

Ends up turning URLs into this though:

```
https://www.example.com/page/sub-page/sub-page/sub-page/sub-page/sub-page/sub-page/sub-page/sub-page/sub-page/sub-page/sub-page/sub-page/sub-page/sub-page/
```

How can I fix? Seems strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect in the same domain just use like below

```
Redirect 301 /page /page/sub-page/
```

To diffenrent domain

```
Redirect 301 /page http://www.example.com/page/sub-page/
```

Hope below link will help you lot
https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489